# For /F loop doesn't work if one of the lines inside the text file has parentheses in Batch

Tags: batch-file

I'm making a script to clean my desktop (and probably other folders) by putting files like .docx, .png, ... in their respective directories (My documents, My pictures). I do this by using the dir /b command to get a list of .docx files, .xlsx files, ... and then put them in a text file named documents.txt. When it runs the part where it moves all the items, I use this code:

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (%~dp0temp\pictures.txt) do (

if exist %picturesLocationNoLQuote%\%%A" (
move "%%A" %picturesLocation%\DuplicateName\
goto :donePictures
)

move "%%A" %picturesLocation%\
:donePictures
)
```

this is pictures.txt:

```
ss+(2015-06-03+at+07.13.21).png
ss+(2015-06-03+at+07.13.37).png
10955654_437759043046259_8344582008026809557_o.jpg
7cZZMDu.jpg
baltimore-riot-police-car-AFP-640x480.jpg
Kirito-sword-art-online-31698905-1280-720.jpg
lol_yasuo_t_shirt4_new_re2_by_zersphaiz-d73cs39.jpg
msi-geforce-gtx-970-gaming-4gb.jpg
Parapente_-_Les_Saisies_02.JPG
people-are-awesome.jpg
project-yasuo-cyber-ops-skin-splash-league-of-legends-1920x1080-hd-wallpaper.jpg
thais-restaurant.jpg
Minecraft.psd
ss+(2015-06-03+at+07.13.21).psd
```

As you can see, there are parentheses in the first file. This throws an error in the for /f loop. I've done some research and I've only found solutions for parentheses in the pathname. So do you guys know how I can fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Labels inside loops are unsupported, use `else`
2. `%~dp0` path may contain spaces, use quotes and `usebackq` option

   ```
   for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%A in ("%~dp0temp\pictures.txt") do (
       if exist "%picturesLocationNoLQuote%\%%A" (
           move "%%A" %picturesLocation%\DuplicateName\
       ) else (
           move "%%A" %picturesLocation%\
       )
   )
   pause
   ```

Comment: %picturesLocationNoLQuote% has an opening quote. %picturesLocation% has opening and closing quotes, and i needed that but without end quotes, so i made %picturesLocationNoLQuote% without the end quote (NoLQuote stands for No Last Quote)

Comment: Well, it might be the cause of batch interpreter confusion because it works as expected when **both** quotes are explicitly present.

Comment: It works now, even without the " before %pictuesLocationNoLQuote%! Thanks!

Comment: Oh, nice to know the batch interpreter isn't completely stupid :-)